# Как объекту при создании приклеить определенное значение?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
object b = new Button();
b.GlueValue(567);

/////

int value = b.GetValue();
```

Comment: чем вас код выше не устраивает?

Comment: Какой код выше? Мне надо к кнопке приклеить значение, которое я буду получать, допустим, при клике на нее.

Answer (score 1):

У класса `Button` в WinForms есть свойство `Tag` типа данных `object`. Туда можно положить все что хочешь. И потом при клике делать, напрмер:

```
var btn = sender as Button
var btnProperty = btn.Tag as T // где T - желаемый тип
```

Comment: А если учесть, что нужно поместить значение в любой объект?

Comment: @Antinet - вообще в любой - это невозможно. Можно написать свой фреймворк, в рамках которого можно будет навешивать дополнительные свойства/методы на любой объект. Наподобие как сделаны attached properties в WPF/XAML. Но работать это будеть только в рамках этого фреймворка. Ну или пишите свой язык (шёпотом: уже есть Nemerle)...

Answer (score 0):

Используйте возможности ООП. Создайте класс кнопки со значением:

```
public class ValueButton : Button
{
    private int _value;

    public void SetValue(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

При желании, можно создать любое количество свойств/полей любого типа.

---

Другой вариант. Используем методы расширения.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetValue(this Control control, int value)
    {
        control.Tag = value;
    }

    public static int GetValue(this Control control)
    {
        return (int)control.Tag;
    }
}
```

Теперь у любого объекта типа `Control` (а это все gui-объекты WinForms) есть методы сохранения-получения значения. Но для хранения используется свойство `Tag`, что ограничивает нас одним значением (можно при желании коллекции использовать).

---

Следующий способ добавляет методы расширения к типу `object`, то есть ко *всем* типам.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    static Dictionary<object, int> dict = new Dictionary<object, int>();

    public static void SetValue(this object @object, int value)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(@object))
            dict[@object] = value;
        else
            dict.Add(@object, value);
    }

    public static int GetValue(this object @object)
    {
        if (dict.TryGetValue(@object, out int value))
            return value;
        else
            return default(int);
    }
}
```

Естественно, это правильно работает только со ссылочными типами.
Для значимых типов и ссылочных типов, копируемых по значению (например, `string`), value будет добавляться именно к значению, а не к переменной.

Comment: Необязательно объект Control, нужно для любого. Для этой задачи подойдет Dictionary<object, int>?

Comment: @Antinet - если вас это устравивает, то подойдёт. Примерно так и сделаны attached properties в WPF.

Comment: @Antinet - обновил ответ.